# Data population in UI form

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, adminform, uicomponent

Im trying to build a custom admin form (using ui components) for a custom entity. We can assume the entity is very simple(e.g. id,name)

One thing that i have hard time with, is populating the form with data.

For this purpose i wrote a custom data provider which looks something like this:

```
public function getData()
{
    if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
        return $this->loadedData;
    }

    $items = $this->collection->getItems();
    /** @var Customer $customer */
    foreach ($items as $faq) {
        $this->loadedData[$faq->getId()] = $faq->getData();
    }

    $data = $this->getSession()->getFormData();
    if (!empty($data)) {
        $faqId = isset($data) ? $data : null;
        $this->loadedData[$faqId] = $data;
        $this->getSession()->unsFormData();
    }

    return $this->loadedData;
}
```

So the actual data are right under the id of the entity.

The ui component has a single fieldset with one field:

```
<fieldset name="general">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Conditions</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <field name="name">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Label</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">name</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">general</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

The problem is, that the field never gets populated. Only way at the moment is to change stracture of the array returned by data provider:

```
$this->loadedData[$faq->getId()]['general'] = $faq->getData();
```

So the structure of the array has the same structure as fieldset -> field in the xml.

This seems to make some sense, however when i look how CMS module is defined for pages and blocks, it doesn't use the fieldset -> field hierarchy.

The data providers don't contain the fieldset key anywhere(or at least not from the getData) method, but the xml uses magical source 'block'.

For example for block

```
\Magento\Cms\Model\Block\DataProvider

public function getData()
{
    if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
        return $this->loadedData;
    }
    $items = $this->collection->getItems();
    /** @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Block $block */
    foreach ($items as $block) {
        $this->loadedData[$block->getId()] = $block->getData();
    }

    $data = $this->dataPersistor->get('cms_block');
    if (!empty($data)) {
        $block = $this->collection->getNewEmptyItem();
        $block->setData($data);
        $this->loadedData[$block->getId()] = $block->getData();
        $this->dataPersistor->clear('cms_block');
    }

    return $this->loadedData;
}

\Magento\Cms\view\ui_component\cms_block_form.xml

<fieldset name="general">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string"/>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <field name="is_active">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enable Block</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">block</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">is_active</item>
                <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="true" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="false" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="number">1</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

Where/How is this 'block' source created?

Do i really need to have the fieldset keys in data returned from the data provider?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using dataPersistor to get Form data, thought you're using getSession

```
$data = $this->getSession()->getFormData();
```

**Save action**

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Scheduler;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    protected $dataPersistor;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
    ) {
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Save actionSave action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        if ($data) {
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('scheduler_id');

            $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Vendor\Module\Model\Scheduler')->load($id);
            if (!$model->getId() && $id) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('This Scheduler no longer exists.'));
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            }

            $model->setData($data);

            try {

                $model->save();
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You saved the Scheduler.'));
                $this->dataPersistor->clear('engraving_scheduler');

                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['scheduler_id' => $model->getId()]);
                }
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the Scheduler.'));
            }

            $this->dataPersistor->set('engraving_scheduler', $data);
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['scheduler_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('scheduler_id')]);
        }
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

**DataProvider**

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Scheduler;

use Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Scheduler\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{

    protected $dataPersistor;

    protected $loadedData;
    protected $collection;


    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection = $collectionFactory->create();
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        foreach ($items as $model) {
            $this->loadedData[$model->getId()] = $model->getData();
        }
        $data = $this->dataPersistor->get('engraving_scheduler');

        if (!empty($data)) {
            $model = $this->collection->getNewEmptyItem();
            $model->setData($data);
            $this->loadedData[$model->getId()] = $model->getData();
            $this->dataPersistor->clear('engraving_scheduler');
        }

        return $this->loadedData;
    }
}
```

**ui form xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">engraving_scheduler_form.scheduler_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">engraving_scheduler_form.scheduler_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">General Information</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">engraving_scheduler_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="back" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Scheduler\Edit\BackButton</item>
            <item name="delete" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Scheduler\Edit\DeleteButton</item>
            <item name="save" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Scheduler\Edit\SaveButton</item>
            <item name="save_and_continue" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Scheduler\Edit\SaveAndContinueButton</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="scheduler_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\Scheduler\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">scheduler_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">scheduler_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">scheduler_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" path="*/*/save" xsi:type="url"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="General">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="label">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Title</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Scheduler</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">label</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes DataPersistor is a better way of doing this (the question is quite dated), but following up with ObjectManager use is not so good.

Comment: this answer gives the clarity for populating the data in UI form.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the the customer edit form and get a look over the array returned by getdata() method . It sends out a array as [id][fieldset_name][data]. So here the key is mentioned during edit action.I guess this is the standard way of loading a UI form with data during edit.

Comment: Yes some of the forms use this and in case of tabbed form like customer it makes sense. However for very simple form this is way too complicated.

The question I really have is, how the cms module doest this? Because the fieldset name is not used there.

Comment: @Langley did you find out much more about this? In the same predicament now. Thanks

Comment: Not that much, but ended up making it work somehow. Cant remember. Looking into the original question i think it may be wrong dataScope in the form configuration (not the fields)

Comment: Each form does contain a fieldset so format of [id][fieldset_name][data] if definitely correct.